# How to label features based on categories in the attribute column of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, attribute-table

I have the below shown attribute table:

[image]

I would like to label the features with the name for the points under the category 'AMN' only as shown in the last column of the above figure. Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Layer Properties - Labels:

[image]

Under Method, switch to Define classes of features and label each class differently. Then select SQL Query and write the following:

```
"FieldName" = 'AMN'
```

[image]

Where FieldName is the field name of the column that contains `'AMN'`

Answer (score -1):

Select your field name under `Label Field` menu as in the picture below.

[image]